# How stackoverflow does their menus

Tags: html, css

Can someone please tell me how stackoverflow gets the the continuous line under their menu:

[image]

I've basically got a main div that's a flex box (no borders set). It contains elements that set the bottom border. However if i want to space the items out like stackoverflow then i get gaps on the bottom line.

Does anyone know how the continuous bottom line is achieved while spacing the items out?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <style>
    #mainContainer {
      padding:30px;
      padding-top:100px;
    }
    #containerDispBar {
      height:40px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
    .dispBarItem {
      display: flex;
      flex-basis: 20%;
      padding:3px;
      justify-content: center;
      border-width:1px;
      border-style:solid;
      margin-left:8px;
    }

    .dispBarItem > span {
      align-self: center;
    }

    .dispBarItem:last-child{
      flex-basis: 60%;
      border:none;
      border-bottom: 1px solid;
    }

    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      border-width:1px;
      border-style:solid;
      border-top:none;
      height:300px;

    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <div id="mainContainer">
      <div id="containerDispBar"> 
        <div class="dispBarItem"><span>A</span> </div>
        <div class="dispBarItem"><span>B</span> </div> 
        <div class="dispBarItem"></div> 
      </div>
      <div class="container"> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I recommend reading the CSS that they use. Start there and *then* ask a **specific** question once you've run into trouble.

Comment: how is your comment constructive. I could say that about any question someone posts on this site. Just read the C book on pointers... Just read a text book on CSS. My question was specific i want to know how to get a continuous line without the gaps at the bottom. If you're going to make a shitty comment like that don't make one at all

Comment: Just ask yourself this. "How do I create 'lines' around elements? And Can I change the visibility of each line, if so, how?"

Comment: @MarMan29, please review [ask], and [invest more of your time into researching questions before asking](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/497418). From reading your question it's clear that you haven't actually taken the time to look at how Stack Overflow does things, and you expect random strangers on the internet to do your work for you for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

The trick is to set `border-bottom` white, and set `margin-bottom: -1px` so the border with overlap on the `.container`'s border.

```css
#mainContainer {
  padding:30px;
  padding-top:100px;
}
#containerDispBar {
  height:40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.dispBarItem {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  padding:3px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left:8px;
}

.selected {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  margin-bottom: -1px;  
}

.dispBarItem > span {
  align-self: center;
}

/*.dispBarItem:last-child{
  flex-basis: 60%;
  border:none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}*/

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-width:1px;
  border-style:solid;
  /*border-top:none;*/
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <style>
    
  </style>

  <body>
    <div id="mainContainer">
      <div id="containerDispBar"> 
        <div class="dispBarItem selected"><span>A</span> </div>
        <div class="dispBarItem"><span>B</span> </div> 
        <!--<div class="dispBarItem"></div>-->
      </div>
      <div class="container"> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```